# Can't save an R scirpt as an R file

Tags: r, save, rstudio, rscript, save-as

I use R Studio on a Windows Computer.
I have a problem with saving R scripts as an R file. I tried to click on "save as" and then give the file a name ending on .R, but it doesn't save the file.
I then find a file with this name on my computer, but it is empty (0KB) and shows nothing when I open it. The whole code is gone.

How can I save an R script properly? What could be the problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does it matter where you try to save the script? Like maybe RStudio has write permissions and can save the script in your Documents folder, but has trouble in other places? Maybe try running RStudio as an Administrator? Maybe try re-installing RStudio...

Comment: This is not a specific programming question, and is "off-topic" as of the stackoverflow guidelines. superuser is the place for software specific questions. However Gregor is absolutely correct in his suggestions. This seems to be an installation or computer error. Try reinstalling your software, including Rstudio and R.